# mode attribute is not working with apex:pageblock in visualforce apge

Tags: visualforce

I have a VF tn which want that after click on 'Edit', User can input.
I have applied mode to "detail" but its showing by default Edit mode.

Visualforce Page API version is 10.0

```
<apex:page standardController="C_Object_Process__c" >

 <apex:form >

 <apex:pageblock mode="detail" id="leadPB" title="Lead Edit">

 <apex:pageblockbuttons >
 <apex:commandbutton action="{!Edit}" value="Edit"></apex:commandbutton>

 </apex:pageblockbuttons>

 <apex:pageblocksection id="AddressInformationPBS" title="Address Information">
 <apex:inputfield value="{!C_Object_Process__c.Street}"></apex:inputfield>
 <apex:outputtext value=""></apex:outputtext>

 </apex:pageblocksection>

 </apex:pageblock>

 </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: How can you use `controller="C_Object_Process__c"`, It should be `standardController="C_Object_Process__c"`

Comment: With `mode` attribute of  `<apex:pageblock` you can not implement edit functionality. This value determines whether lines are drawn separating field values. You have to write controller extension to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was in line of code

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!C_Object_Process__c.Street}"></apex:inputfield>
```

After using below line of code its working

```
<apex:outputField value="{!C_Object_Process__c.Street}"/>
```